# evaluating this boolean expression in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to do this boolean expression in perl and my code is supposed to be like this

```
enter code here

 $flag = 0;
  while (<INFILE>)
{

if(/name/ && $flag==0)
 {
   $flag = 1;

 print "HELLO\n";
 }
elsif($flag)
{
  print "Bye\n";
```

My plan is to write something like this

```
flag=0
while<>
if(/name/ && !flag)
flag=1;
elsif(flag)
last;
```

So is there anything wrong in what i did in the code what i reproduced? Is this the way of declaring a true and false value in perl

Comment: Code blocks need a blank line before and after; also indent 4 spaces. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Dear God...please....make it stop....
Your first order of business is to run outside (forget about getting dressed) and buying a copy of Perl Best Practices or other similar book.

To be more helpful and not just provide wise-ass remarks: Read on using strict and warnings, lexical variables, and so on.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. I can't tell what you're asking for, either. Are you asking if this kind of "if not flag set, set flag else other action" logic is a good idea?

Comment: @Sorpigal yes because i tried running it and gives me an error at the the else statement

Comment: well the code just executed without doing anything.I tried printing dummy lines after the if as well as else statement but it does not print.

Comment: At the top of the file put `use strict; use warnings;`. Don't write any more perl or ask any more questions until you've done this.

Comment: @Christoffer I am very new to perl and its been 2 weeks i have been using this language.I apologize if I have overlooked certain concepts.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` is the first thing you should put at the top of all your perl files. It will catch most errors. It should really be the default. Also, try `use diagnostics;` for more helpful error messages.

Comment: thanks i shall keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Use%20strict%20warnings%20and%20diagnostics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment below:

```
while (<>) {
    $flag = 1 if /name/;
    if ($flag) {
        # do something
    }
}
```

Or you can do:

```
while (<>) { last if /name/ }
while (<>) {
    # do something
}
```

Comment: no no i am not doing that. I am searching for /name/ and then if i find it, i start putting the lines from the line where /name/ occurred first till the end into an array.This is just the dummy outline of the code.

Comment: @kun Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is:

In Perl, 0 or '' is considered false.  A non-zero number (1, 42, etc) or string of length greater than 0 ( 'true', 'foo' ) is considered true.